# Why unit circle has radius 1

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm looking for how demonstrate why unit circle has radius 1, but I don't know how start.

Please I need a hint.

Comment: In truth, it doesn't matter.  Just a radius of $1$ happens to be most simple for the equations.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why $\cos^2 x+ \sin^2 x = 1$?

Comment: Definition, by definition, that is why

Comment: I want to understand why 1? Why not 2 or 3.

Comment: @copper.hat You could pick a right-angled triangle with any non-zero length of hypotenuse and $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta \equiv 1$ would still hold.

Comment: "Trigonometric circle" is not standard mathematical terminology in English. The standard terminology in English is "unit circle".

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak english.

Comment: Because that's what "unit" means. "Unit" means $1,$ "unit circle" means circle of radius $1.$

Comment: A unit circle by definition has radius 1.  That's what unit circle means.  This the *first* thing you know about a unit circle.

Comment: "Unit" means 1 unit.  If the radius were 2 or 3 we wouldn't call it a "unit".  Are you asking why we *like* the radius 1 instead of 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sine, Cosine and Tangent are ratios of lengths.

If you chose a circle of radius 2 then you would have made all lengths and all heights twice as big. When you divide these new lengths and heights, the common factor of 2 would cancel.

$$ \sin \theta = \frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}} = \frac{(2\times\text{opp})}{(2 \times\text{hyp})} = \frac{(3 \times \text{opp})}{(3 \times \text{hyp})} = \cdots$$

Picking the radius (hypotenuse) to have length one is the most convenient choice.

Comment: Just it? So, I can choose a another number if I want. 1 it's an ordinary number (but I can pikeup 2 or 100)

Comment: @BrunoRozendo You can pick any non-zero radius you want. The only difference is the intermediate steps would involve bigger numbers. But these bigger numbers will cancel down to give the usual answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x,y) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$$

If you choose a different radius (and thereby, a different hypotenuse length), you lose the simplicity.